# Python - removing duplicates from ordered list of complex objects?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have list of several milions of dictionaries produced from json in form like this:

```
{
  "_id":XXX,
  "some_other":"fields",
  ...
}
```

List needs to be safe-sorted by `_id` key however there are disctionaries with duplicated `_id`. There's really few duplicates comparing to size of list (around 10-100 at most). I want to take only first (or last, doesn't matter as long as it's deterministic) dictionary for each duplicated `_id`. In JavaScript I'd use following:

```
list.sort((a,b)=>a._id>b._id?1:(a._id<b._id?-1:0))
    .filter((ent,i,arr)=>i==0||ent!=arr[i-1])
```

However I guess python variant of filter doesn't allow accessing index of item? Is there any similarly short way to accomplish such thing in Python? I found `sorted(...)` function that allows me to sort this list the way I want, however I still don't know how to filter out following duplicates (without obvious, brute for loop).

Comment: have you looked at `sorted` and `filter`? Python has `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` constructs, and you could write an equivalent expression with Python's (a bit unwieldy) anonymous function syntax, using `lambda args: <expression with args>`... Although, for filtering/mapping, frequently list-comprehensions (and related constructs, e.g. `dict` comprehensions, `set` comprehensions, or even generator expressions) are considered more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to remove duplicates (this will always keep the last occurrence for each _id):

```
d = {i['_id']: i for i in your_list}
```

Then sort its values by _id:

```
list(sorted(d.values(), key=lambda i: i['_id']))
```

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic way, in python, would be:

```
import itertools
import operator

get_id = operator.itemgetter('_id') #factory function: lambda x:x['_id']
grouped = itertools.groupby(sorted(json_data, key=get_id), get_id)

result = [next(g) for k,g in grouped]
```

Note, the built-in python `sorted` is an stable-sort, using an adaptive merge-sort called timsort.

`itertools` is a very useful module, implementing various lazy-iterators efficiently. [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is a grouping iterator:

```
# [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B
# [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
```

You can create a transliteration of your javascript, using python anonymous functions and a ternary operator (in Python, a "conditional expression"). Note, Python's `sorted` function doesn't use a comparator function, it uses a [key-based function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`. The default
>   value is `None` (compare the elements directly).

In Python 2, a `cmp` argument that works similarly to the Javascript version still is available (e.g. a function that returns -1, 1, or 0)

`cmp` was deprecated and finally removed in Python 3 in favor of `key`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sorted`, `filter`, and `map`:

```
d = [
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "some_other": "a"
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "some_other": "b"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "some_other": "c"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "some_other": "d"
    }
]

sorted_d = sorted(d, key=lambda x: x['_id'])
map(
    lambda y: y[1],
    filter(
        lambda x: True if x[0]==0 else sorted_d[x[0]]["_id"] != sorted_d[x[0]-1]["_id"],
        enumerate(sorted_d)
    )
)
```

Output:

```
[{'_id': 1, 'some_other': 'b'},
 {'_id': 2, 'some_other': 'c'},
 {'_id': 3, 'some_other': 'a'}]
```